# Unable to upload apk to Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I'm trying to automate my app build distribution via Jenkyns and Crashlytics. I configured all as indicated on the documentation but crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease failed with this error: "Distribution upload failed" and "WARN - Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't distribute the unsigned APK:".

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here.

Beta for Android only supports distributing a signed APK, unsigned APKs can't be distributed.

For information on how to sign an Android app, head to Android's documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: you also have to check both V1 & V2 signature versions if signing from Android Studio otherwise it will complain that it's unsigned for some reason..

Comment: I was able to upload unsigned apk to crashlytics by adding:  apk_path:

Comment: Hi Mike, I know how to generate signed APK, and i have generated signed APK successfully, but still facing same issues

Comment: Are you getting a different warning?

Comment: I'm getting the same warning. I have even turned off Instant Run and made sure that I am online

Comment: Where is this info "Beta for Android only supports distributing a signed APK, unsigned APKs can't be distributed." in the official Crashlytics documentation? 

Very very poor documentation :[ I had to google it for 1h to find this info

Comment: I'd recommend contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io with any suggestions for improving the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Crashlytics not support "Android App Bundle". You can only distrubute "APK" in crashlytics beta.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue when I was integrating Fastlane with
   Crashlytics. I wanted to distribute build to testers.

In Fastlane, you can choose whether you want to publish Debug APK or
   Release APK. Fastlane trying to publish release APK I just changed it
   to Debug APK in a Fastfile and it worked.

I am sure it might have some settings in Jenkins also that could publish
   Debug APK. hope this helps.

Comment: How can I choose Debug APK to publish?

Comment: @AntonBalashov In a fastfile there is an option like
build_android_app(task: "assembleRelease")
replace it to
build_android_app(task: "assembleDevelop")